# Conditionally Importing CSS files for IE7/8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, import, conditional-statements

I am wondering if there is a way to conditionally import CSS files for IE7/8 at the CSS level instead of using IE conditional comments.

I'd like to create a SASS solution for loading Google Fonts, but to make them work in IE7/8 requires that different styles be loaded separately. This however is undesired when not needed due to latency and Opera rendering issues.

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of another way of conditional loading IE specific styles.  You've got two options but both use conditional comments.

### Load a separate stylesheet

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <style type="text/css" src="bacon-ie.css"> </style>
<![endif]-->
```

### Add IE class names

```
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<html lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

And then use them to add specific browser styles.

```
.ie7 .make-work {
    zoom: 1;
}
```